# Instantiate gameobject between 2 objects in unity 3d

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have 2 objects. It will be in various direction and distance.

How can i instantiate objects between them with a specific distance.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion would be to calculate the vector between the two objects, like this

```
Vector3 objectLine = (object2.transform.position - object1.transform.position);
```

Store the magnitude of that vector

```
float distance = objectLine.magnitude;
```

Then, normalise the vector;

```
objectLine = objectLine.normalized;
```

Iterate through the line, instantiating the object you want to create a specific distances

```
Vector3 creationPoint = object1.transform.position;
float creationPointDistance = (object1.transform.position - 
    object1.transform.position);
while(creationPointDistance < distance)
{
    creationPoint += objectLine * NEW_OBJECT_DISTANCE;
    creationPointDistance = (object1.transform.position - 
        object1.transform.position);
    if(creationPointDistance < distance)
    {
        objects.Add((GameObject)Instantiate(newObject, creationPoint, 
            new Vector3(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f)));
    }
}
```

What that will do is set the initial point to be object1's position. It will then move a set distance along the vector between object 1 and object 2, check it's within the two objects, and if it is, instantiate the object, storing it in a list of gameobjects.

That hopefully should do it. I don't have Unity (or any IDE) in front of me to check the syntax.

Answer (score 7):

```
var centerLocation : Vector3 = Vector3.Lerp(object2.transform.position - object1.transform.position, 0.5);
```

Vector3.Lerp will determine the Vector3 location between 2 Vector3s at a specified percentage. 0.5 = 50%.

Comment: much more elegant solution, this should be the accepted answer