# instantiate plane with texture between two objects(vectors)

Tags: vector, unity-game-engine, instantiation, unityscript

First a little context.
I am attempting to build a little fence-builder functionality.
Below is a sketch showing idea/how I see it approached.
Ohh not enough rep apparently: link here: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/NachD.jpg][1]
Two objects are instantiated(Pole1 & Pole2)
As I in runtime move those two poles around the terrain, I wish to
a: create a plane with a texture between those poles (a tileable transparent fence thingy)
which in update ofcourse scales according to the distance between those two points/poles.

b: instantiate new poles according to distance between the two poles.

So far I have per pictures linked two poles I can drag around and a third pole being placed exactly between those two.
I found another post: [Instantiate gameobject between 2 objects in unity 3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17231299/instantiate-gameobject-between-2-objects-in-unity-3d)
But couldn't get code from "SlxS"  to work, and it does not really aid in me creating a textured plane/cube between the poles.

Code that works:

```
    function Update () 
    {
        poles.transform.position = 0.5f*(pole1.transform.position + pole2.transform.position);
    }
    var pole1 : Transform;
    var pole2 : Transform;
    
    var poles : GameObject;
    
    
    var selectedDistance : int = 5;
    function Build()
    {
        var distance = Vector3.Distance(pole1.transform.position,pole2.transform.position);
        print(distance);
    
        
        poles.transform.position = 0.5f*(pole1.transform.position + pole2.transform.position);
        
        if((pole1.transform.position - pole2.transform.position).magnitude < selectedDistance)
        {
            print("more than 5 apart");
        }
        else
        {
            print("less than 5 apart");
        }
    }
```

Hope to get some input :)
Best,
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NachD.jpg

**SOLVED**: Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/685314/joetjah

Code:

```
function Update () 
{
    poles.transform.position = 0.5f*(pole1.transform.position + pole2.transform.position);
}
var pole1 : Transform;
var pole2 : Transform;

var poles : Transform;
function Build2() {
    var poleDistance : Vector2;    
    
    poles.localScale.z = Vector3.Distance(pole1.position,pole2.position); // Find the distance between 2 points
    print(poles.localScale.z);
    poles.LookAt(pole2);
}
```

Comment: Why didn't you 'get the code to work'? What went wrong? Even though I believe that answer (and question) is completely different from what you want. Why don't you take the location values of the poles (you don't need the height, just the x and y I presume) and use that. First you'll need the starting coordinates (first pole). Then you need the ending coordinates (second pole) to create the angle to which your object is turned. Using that angle, you can rotate your fence to match.

Comment: A reason for the code I linked to not working is that apparently I cannot convert Vector to Float. Spent some hours on it, but could not fix it.
How can I use the positions to control a spawned object? I mean it is not so much the turning, I figured that by using the Distance(vector) between those points could help in both controlling direction and scale of lets say a cube. But I am blank on how to control an object from two other transforms besides what I showed in the code.
EDIT: top line add

Comment: You could try to set the transform.position of the fence to the same position as the pole.transform.position. As far as your example goes, where do you try to convert Vector3 to float? Vector3.magnitude is something different then Vector3...

Comment: But how can I then 'draw' a cube to the other pole's position.
Looked at procedural mesh, but cant see why it should be that complicated.
I guess the analogy is: One stick in the ground(pole1), another stick(pole2) in the ground 'somewhere'.. BOOM a wall is suddenly between those points. :)

Comment: Let me try to explain: Say you have two poles, which are both 1 in height (z-axis?). The location of the first pole (P1) is on x=2 and y=1. P2: (5, 5). That would mean the left side of your rectangle (not cube..) would be on (2,1), with 1 height. The right side of your rectangle has to be on (5,5), also with 1 height. Think of it as drawing a line. The starting point of your line is the first pole, and the ending of your line is the second pole.

Comment: yes exactly. Since those two positions might change it would be handled within Update or so. But how to actually create the rectangle between those points?
At point A(pole1) I could scale rectangle.transform.position.x with my 'Distance'. This would send it the exact distance to B point(pole 2). Right? then how is the rotation handled. Using some form of LookAt()   ?   btw, thanks for your input so far.

Comment: Hmmm. You could try to use Vector3.Angle to get the angle between the two points. Then rotate your object so it's in line. Then get the distance so you know how long it has to be. Then you'd be ready, no? LookAt might help but I'm not sure how the object would turn. You can try transform.rotate to rotate the object with the same angle as you retrieve from `Vector3.Angle(pole1.transform, pole2.transform);`

Comment: I'm just theorycrafting here haha, I can't test anything so that makes it hard for me to give decent answers.

Comment: first; the scaling stuff works great.
When I try to add the returned Angle(which is in float), I am told that I cannot convert. I have tried all kinds of code etc. Still struggle. This works: poles.transform.position = pole1.transform.position;
 poles.transform.localScale = new Vector3(distance,1,1);
 
 poles.transform.position = 0.5f*(pole1.transform.position + pole2.transform.position);
The other stuff is still in the winds..