# Instantiate object(s) between two other objects

Tags: unity-game-engine

Im currently able to move two objects(two fence poles) around and stretch an object in between acting as a wire in a fence.
Have a look at the solved question here for further info: [instantiate plane with texture between two objects(vectors)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18376411/instantiate-plane-with-texture-between-two-objectsvectors)

I would appreciate some input on how I can instantiate poles in between as well as having the wire which already works. 
For instance every time the distance between the two objects rises with e.g. 1.
I compute distance like this:
        Vector3.Distance(currentPole1.position,currentPole2.position));

And guess a for loop could do the check, but can't seem to figure this one out.
thnx,
Kro

Answer (score 0):

Given two Vector3 coordinates, `p1` and `p2`, we could calculate X points evenly spaced between them:

```
Vector3 p1 = <some vector>
Vector3 p2 = <some vector>
int numPoints = 9;

float step = 1f / (numPoints+1);
for (float perc = step; perc < 1f; perc += step) {
    Vector3 v = Vector3.Lerp(p1, p2, perc);
    //do something at position v
}
```

Or we could calculate several points, each spaced at most X units apart:

```
Vector3 p1 = <some vector>
Vector3 p2 = <some vector>
float maxSpacing = 10f;

Vector3 diff = p2 - p1;
Vector3 dir = diff.normalized;
float totalDistance = diff.magnitude;
for (float dist = maxDistance; dist < totalDistance; dist += maxSpacing ) {
    Vector3 v = p1 + dir * dist;
    //do something at position v
}
```

(Just noticed my sample code is in C#, where your previous question was using JS; presumably you can work out the difference?)

Comment: Hey Rutter,
Thnx for your answer.
I tried to rewrite first block and using the two poles as p1 & p2
        var p1 : Vector3 = currentPole1.TransformDirection(Vector3.right);
 var p2 : Vector3 = currentPole2.TransformDirection(Vector3.left);
 var numPoints : int = 9;

 var step : float = 1f / (numPoints+1);
 for (var perc : float = step; perc < 1f; perc += step) {
     var v : Vector3 = Vector3.Lerp(p1, p2, perc);
     
     //do something at position v
     Instantiate(fencePoleSkew, v, Quaternion.identity);
this instantiates the object but not between the two poles.

Comment: I also rewrote the second block
         var p1 : Vector3 = currentPole1.position.x(Vector3.up);
 var p2 : Vector3 = currentPole2.position.x(Vector3.up);
 var maxSpacing : float = 10f;
 var maxDistance : float;
 var diff : Vector3 = p2 - p1;
 var dir : Vector3 = diff.normalized;
 var totalDistance : float = diff.magnitude;
 var dist: float = maxDistance;
 for(dist < totalDistance; dist += maxSpacing) 
 {
     var v : Vector3 = p1 + dir * dist;
     //do something at position v
 }
This gives me some errors in the for loop.
e.g.  expecting ;, found '+='.
Unexpected token: maxSpacing.

Comment: I did this to instantiate a pole between the two other poles:
        var point:Vector3;
 point.x = currentPole1.transform.position.x + 0.5*(currentPole2.transform.position.x - currentPole1.transform.position.x);
 point.z = currentPole1.transform.position.z + 0.5*(currentPole2.transform.position.z - currentPole1.transform.position.z);
        var instance = Instantiate(fencePoleSkew, point, Quaternion.identity);